# Delegateing a file input to a div click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below snippet. Why am I not able to delegate the FileUpload to a div `img-box`?. I just want to hide the original input and load image by clicking on plus sign instead

```js
$('.img-box').click(function(e) {
  console.log("Test");
    e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).find('input[name="image"]').click();
});
```

```css
.img-box{
  min-height:100px;
  min-width:100px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements/700/07_plus-128.png");
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
}

input {
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail ">
      <div class="img-box">
  <input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
<img id="i" class="img-responsive" />
       
      </div>  
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you use `input[type=image]` but it is `type=file` and `name=image`

```
$(this).find('input[type="image"]').click();
```

you have to use

```
$(this).find('input[name="image"]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks Osama I update the code and I am getting new error now

Comment: Please run the snippet again. you will see it on screen

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Also, if you care about performance, selecting an element by input[name="image"] is not the fastest way. Give your input an ID and select by id $("#myInputId"). Alternatively you can give your input a class attribute and select it using $(".myInputClass") for a fast performance